# positioning of slider and text

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I have one  content 'manufactures' it needs to display in the center but it is displaying in the right side. and I want to display the image slider fully equivalent to the header part
but when i try it is not expanding.This is my [site](http://www.discountedlens.com.au/)

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the `float:left`  for the parent div of h4 tag. and increase the   `margin-left` as 630px

```
div.block {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.blockmanufacturer h4 {
  color: #CB5C3A;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  margin-left: 630px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your CSS for the Manufactures header

```
.blockmanufacturer h4 {margin-left: 450px; color:#cb5c3a; font-size:12px; margin-bottom:0.2em; padding-bottom:1em;}
```

Even if you center aligned the div / centered the text of its containing div, since you've added *margin-left: 450px* The text is going to be off centered to the right. Try taking that out and/or changing the margin to something like 0px auto;

If you still are having the issue try adding *text-align: center* to your h4 or it's parent's class.

There maybe some other issue completely seperate from what I've mentioned here thats making the issue worse, but it's impossible to tell with out looking over the CSS and HTML code. (And I don't have enough time to manually pull out all your code and look it over through firebug / developer tools)